# Anonymous Access

Tags: sharepoint-online, anonymous-authentication, public-website

I am trying to set up anonymous access for a sub site on SharePoint 365.

We are not hosting this on our own server yet with Microsoft.

I have looked high and low from forums telling me how to setup this access.
I need this to work like a public facing website without credentials to login and view it.

How can i set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 gives you one site where you can enable anonymous access, the Public site.

It is not possible to activate anonymous access on other sites.

Comment: How would i go about getting this access?

Comment: In the public site, there is a link in the top right to toggle between private and public